# Access current_user from within Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I am building an Invoicing Application that basically follows the following pattern:

`Users < Clients < Projects < Invoices`

Now in order to generate autoincrementing invoice numbers for each User I put this in my `Invoice` model:

```
  before_create :create_invoice_number

  def create_invoice_number
    val = @current_user.invoices.maximum(:number)
    self.number = val + 1
  end
```

However, it seems that the current_user variable cannot be accessed from within models in Rails?

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: What are you using for authentication? Usually they give you a method like `current_user`, not an instance variable like `@current_user`. Or do you manually create `@current_user` somewhere? If so, you'll have to pass it along or store it in a session variable or something.

Answer (score 10):

This is due to separation of concerns in Rails and is a somewhat sticky issue to deal with. In the Rails paradigm, models should have no knowledge of any application state beyond what they're passed directly, so most Rails coders will tell you that any model needing to know about a current_user is code smell.

That said, there are three ways to do this, each "more correct" (or at least I would consider them so).

First, try creating an association to the user inside the invoice and link the invoice to the user in the controller:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

...

def create
  @invoice = current_user.invoices.create(params[:invoice])
  ...
end
```

And in your model:

```
belongs_to :user

def create_invoice_number
  self.user.invoices.maximum(:number) + 1
end
```

If that doesn't work, do this manually in the controller. It's true that controllers should always be as skinny as you can manage, but since this is clearly an application-level concern the controller is the place to put it:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

...

def create
  @invoice = Invoice.create(params[:invoice])
  @invoice.update_attribute(:number, current_user.invoices.maximum(:number))
  ...
end
```

Lastly, if you really, really want to bridge the controller and model, you can do so with [ActionController::Sweepers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Caching/Sweeping.html). They are not intended for this purpose but will certainly get the job done for you.

Comment: Absolutely, accessing the current user from within a model is a code smell. +1

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. The first version doesn't work because somehow the `current_user`method can't be used in models. The second version works but looks a bit ugly to me because it bloats my controller...

Comment: The first version is intended to go in the controller, not the model.

Comment: How would you reduce the number of queries using eager loading? If you put it in the controller, and you're trying to access a join table, it does it for each main object record, rather than access loaded join records. Am I just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

there should not be any arise of such case still if you want then make use of `observers` in rails

Comment: you have to understand first how observers gets defined and works ?

Comment: @Veraticus answer should be fulfilling what you want ...dnt make things to complex when they are not actually ;)